# Anchor moves to right when clicking it on Firefox, using HTML5, CSS3 and HTML5Boilerplate

Tags: css, html5boilerplate

I am developing my first website using html5boilerplate and I'm experiencing a strange thing. When doing an anchor and clicking it, it moves to the right. This it only happens on Firefox and not on Chrome, for example.

You can see an example of this with my exact CSS: http://jsfiddle.net/PuEzv/

How I can solve it?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Its a bit late to answer, but still:

Remove or modify following code to avoid the "jumping" for all links:

```
#submenu a, a:active, a:visited {color:#f1f1f0; margin-left:1px; margin-right: 1px;}
```

To keep it enabled for `#submenu`, I think you muste write your css selectors like this:

```
#submenu a,#submenu a:active,#submenu a:visited {color:#f1f1f0; margin-left:1px; margin-right: 1px;}
```

I hope that helped!